# Download proteowizard for ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install proteowizard `pwiz-bin-linux-x86_64-gcc48-release-3_0_11537.tar.bz2` from  http://proteowizard.sourceforge.net/downloads.shtml using the command `mkdir pwiz; tar xvf pwiz*.tar.bz2 -C pwiz`, shown at http://tools.proteomecenter.org/wiki/index.php?title=Msconvert_Wine.

It does not work.  I get the error:

```
tar: pwiz*.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Where did you store the downloaded archive? What's the output of `ls -l` in that directory?

Answer (score 2):

- Wrong method

This works:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
mkdir pwiz/
mv pwiz-bin-linux-x86_64-gcc48-release-3_0_11537.tar.bz2 pwiz/
cd pwiz/
tar xvjf pwiz-bin-linux-x86_64-gcc48-release-3_0_11537.tar.bz2
```

and it will echo the extraction ...

```
./
./chainsaw
./unimod_2.xsd
./pepsum
./txt2mzml
./msconvert
./idconvert
./mspicture
./msbenchmark
./peakaboo
./quantitation_1.xsd
./pepcat
./idcat
./mscat
./qtofpeakpicker
./msdir
./sldout
./msdiff
./msaccess
./msistats
./quantitation_2.xsd
```

Comment: Thank you!.  How do I download the tar.bz2 file from linux?